# Character hitTest Wall

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest

The problem with my current platform game project is that the character stops before hitting a wall on the character's left side, and stops too late on the right side of the character.

[image: CharacterLeftHitTest]

[image: CharacterRightHitTest]

Here is the script related to the problem:

```
char.topBumping=false;
char.bottomBumping=false;
char.leftBumping=false;
char.rightBumping=false;

char.speed=0;
char.maxSpeedConstant=10;
char.minSpeedConstant=-10;

char.xVel=0;
char.yVel=0;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,EnterFrame);
function EnterFrame(e:Event){


    //local points
    top_left_point_local = new Point(char.top_left.x,char.top_left.y);
    bottom_left_point_local = new Point(char.bottom_left.x,char.bottom_left.y);

    top_right_point_local = new Point(char.top_right.x,char.top_right.y);
    bottom_right_point_local = new Point(char.bottom_right.x,char.bottom_right.y);

    //global points
    top_left_point = new Point(char.localToGlobal(top_left_point_local).x,char.localToGlobal(top_left_point_local).y);
    bottom_left_point = new Point(char.localToGlobal(bottom_left_point_local).x,char.localToGlobal(bottom_left_point_local).y);

    top_right_point = new Point(char.localToGlobal(top_right_point_local).x,char.localToGlobal(top_right_point_local).y);
    bottom_right_point = new Point(char.localToGlobal(bottom_right_point_local).x,char.localToGlobal(bottom_right_point_local).y);


    if(ground.hitTestPoint(top_left_point.x,top_left_point.y,true)){
        char.leftBumping=true;
    }
    if(ground.hitTestPoint(bottom_left_point.x,bottom_left_point.y,true)){
        char.leftBumping=true;
    }


    if(!ground.hitTestPoint(top_left_point.x,top_left_point.y,true)&&!ground.hitTestPoint(bottom_left_point.x,bottom_left_point.y,true)){
        char.leftBumping=false;
    }


    if(ground.hitTestPoint(top_right_point.x,top_right_point.y,true)){
        char.rightBumping=true;
    }
    if(ground.hitTestPoint(bottom_right_point.x,bottom_right_point.y,true)){
        char.rightBumping=true;
    }
    if(!ground.hitTestPoint(top_right_point.x,top_right_point.y,true)&&!ground.hitTestPoint(bottom_right_point.x,bottom_right_point.y,true)){
        char.rightBumping=false;
    }

    if(char.rightBumping){
        if(char.xVel>0){
            char.xVel=0;
            char.speed=0;
        }
    }
    if(char.leftBumping){
        if(char.xVel<0){
            char.xVel=0;
            char.speed=0;
        }
    }


    char.x+=char.xVel;
    char.y+=char.yVel;

}
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Any help will be much appreciated.

Update:

This is the heart of the problem, for some reason the character hitting the left wall comes out true here even while the character is standing still (left is not being pressed).

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an issue with chopping off how much movement should be made as the character nears objects by simply checking what the characters velocity is when they are near objects.  For example, if their velocity is 5 and they are 4 pixels away from the object, only let the player move 4 pixels so they line up with the object.

Comment: I see what your saying Sly Raskal, but how would you propose I fulfill this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after many aggravating hours I finally solved the problem. The orientation of the inside of a movieclip determines its overall position. I never knew that. I always thought it didn't matter how the inside of a movieclip was positioned in relation to the movieclip's center. Lesson learned, always center the inside of movieclips to the mc's stage to simplify things.